# Looking for resources for supervised learning on video classification

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, references, computer-vision, audio

I have quite a generic problem. I have a collection of videos, and a collection of tags that identify an action on a specific timestamp. I wish to be able to classify the correct neighborhoods of such events using these videos (which consist of both frames images and audio).
Even though there are many great sources for audio analysis and computer vision, I find it hard to come by a good ("for dummies") tutorial for this kind of generic problem. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1E3mOTtKtCo&list=PLtGXgNsNHqPRAscIi6dMUuPCfDQ1Vho2U&index=3&ab_channel=TalhaAnwar) YouTube collection is almost the only one I found, that demonstrates how to work with videos and utilize `torchvideo`. I am sure there are other resources as well. Any tutorial will be greatly appreciated.

**p.s.**: Surprisingly, just to give an example of the scarcity there is of video analysis discussions (and hence tools and tutorials, that come usually to meet the demand of people working with videos), there is no "video" tag.